# Is it possible to move an ADO.NET EF (edmx file) from one project to another?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, project, move

I need to move my **edmx** file from one project to another. Both projects are **ASP.NET MVC3** projects in C#.

The destination project is an **intranet project** as created by Visual Studio 2010, without any additional classes or code.

Is it possible to move the edmx file and have all the plumbing (such as web.config modification) done by Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Better make a separate project containing the edmx and add its reference to other projects

Comment: thanks. However I want to delete the project where the edmx is currently (it is a test project)  and move it to the new one

Comment: Have you tried opening the new solution and right clicking on the Model folder, select Add Existing item and browse to the edmx file in the old solution?